# Adding 2nd flyway instance in new schema

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I have an existing app, with an existing flyway migration script. It uses the `public` schema of the database it connects to.

I'm working on a 2nd app that, for database purposes, will access the `public` and `ABC` schema, with read-access to `public` and read/write access to `ABC`. I'd like the 2nd app to handle its own flyway migration scripts for schema `ABC`. This app's instance of flyway can ignore the public schema completely.

When I run the app, I get the following in my logs

```
2018-12-04 09:16:02.871  WARN 71133 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.c.i.s.JdbcTableSchemaHistory         : Could not find schema history table "public"."flyway_schema_history", but found "public"."schema_version" instead. You are seeing this message because Flyway changed its default for flyway.table in version 5.0.0 to flyway_schema_history and you are still relying on the old default (schema_version). Set flyway.table=schema_version in your configuration to fix this. This fallback mechanism will be removed in Flyway 6.0.0.
2018-12-04 09:16:02.904  INFO 71133 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.core.internal.command.DbValidate     : Successfully validated 49 migrations (execution time 00:00.028s)
2018-12-04 09:16:02.935  INFO 71133 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Current version of schema "public": 201808271553
2018-12-04 09:16:02.935  WARN 71133 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Schema "public" has version 201808271553, but no migration could be resolved in the configured locations !
2018-12-04 09:16:02.940  INFO 71133 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Schema "public" is up to date. No migration necessary.
```

This is my `application.yaml`

```
flyway:
  url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/data
  schemas: ABC
  table: schema_version_module1
  user: flyway
  password: flyway
```

I'd like flyway to use the mqa schema (that I've created manually) for everything, instead of relying on the public schema for the migration history.

This is a spring boot java app, with `flyway-core:5.2.3` defined in my build.gradle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flyway 5.0.7 warning about using schema\_version table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49063385/flyway-5-0-7-warning-about-using-schema-version-table)

Comment: This question is about using a schema besides `public`, not the flyway history table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Flyway config should be put under the Spring namespace starting with Spring Boot 2.0. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-use-a-higher-level-database-migration-tool