# Does flyway support sql migrations under test folder?

Tags: spring-boot, maven-3, flyway, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am migrating a project from Spring Boot 1.5.21 to 2.2.5. I have followed all instructions in the [guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide). However, I have an issue with flyway (upgrading from 4.2.0 to 6).

Previously, when I had sql migration files under `src/test/resources/db/migration`, flyway would run them as part of the `mvn clean install` command. Now, for some reason, it stopped running these migrations (Just to clarify, I'm talking about `maven` build and not while running the app).

I'm using `maven 3.6.3` and `flyway-maven-plugin version 6.0.8` with the following configuration (some values are tokens which are irrelevant for this question):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${flyway.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>migrate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <skip>${db.skip}</skip>
        <url>${db.url}</url>
        <user>${db.username}</user>
        <password>${db.password}</password>
        <locations>
            <location>classpath:db/migration</location>
        </locations>
        <schemas>public,downstream</schemas>
        <outOfOrder>true</outOfOrder>
        <callbacks>
            db.migration.callback.PopulateControlFieldsFlywayCallback,db.migration.callback.UpdateReplicaIdentityFlywayCallback,db.migration.callback.UpdateSchemaHistoryTableFlywayCallback
        </callbacks>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Why did the behaviour changed? How to revert to old behaviour? Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try to run maven build with debug logs?

Comment: One comment, which not connected with your issue. Please note that migration logs in flyway 4 are placed in `schema_versions` table, but in flyway 6 - in `flyway_schema_history`. Note it when will update your PROD code. You can read about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49063385/flyway-5-0-7-warning-about-using-schema-version-table

Comment: @MaximPopov - I have ran maven build with debug logs and compared the before and after my change and couldn't find the cause. Also, I'm aware of the change in the metadata table name and I'm handling it (renaming my old table via flyway callback), but as you noted, it is unrelated since the issue happens even on a new environment.

Comment: Am I understand right that the maven build just stop and do nothing? Could you share the logs before this moment?

Comment: @MaximPopov Maven fails since I use Jooq to generate classes from DB tables, but the table I need classes generated from is the one that should have been created in the sql migration that stopped running, so the error in the log is the result of the issue and not the cause which is the flyway behaviour change

Comment: Ok. I got it. Which previous `flyway-maven-plugin` version did you use? And am I understand right, that you haven't changed any `flyway-maven-plugin` configurations, especially locations?

Comment: I have reproduced your issue and found that it happens on upgrade `maven-flyway-plugin` from `4.2.0` to `5.0.0`. I will try to investigate it

Comment: @MaximPopov - You are correct, I haven't changed any other ```flyway-maven-plugin``` configurations and indeed I'm upgrading from version 4.2.0 of the plugin. Thank you for investigating! waiting to hear about what you find.

Comment: I debugged the ```flyway-maven-plugin``` and compared the "before" and "after" my change and didn't find the cause... Looks to me it wasn't suppose to work like that in the first place and was simply removed, but don't know for sure. For now I moved the ```sql``` migrations to db/test/migration and added it to <Locations> in Maven. Ugly solution but works for now. @MaximPopov (Or anybody else) - Let me know if your investigation bared fruit.

Comment: I have posted my results in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have dug in the `flyway` and `flyway-maven-plugin` sorces. I have found that the path from classpath location tag is searched by `ClassRealm` in class. And there is exist two classpathes: `ClassRealm[plugin>org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:5.0.0, parent: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@1f89ab83]`. `ClassRealm` is a classloader that is used in Maven.

I have executed `classLoader.getResources('/db/migration')`and found that it returns 2 paths (`target/classes/db/migration` and `target/test-classes/db/migration`) for mave-plugin version `4.2.0`, but returns only 1 path (`target/classes/db/migration) for version`5.0.0`.

Also I have found that there was a commit in flyway-maven-plugin repository for using maven 3 instead of 2 between `maven-plugin` version 4.2.0 and 5.0.0.

I haven't found an exact reason, but, summarizing all, I guess that there were some changes in maven-plugin (I guess some maven core library version) as a result of which the finding path in classpath was changed.

I have tried several options for returning the old behavior, but all of these not so good. These are work:

1. Stay on 4.2.0 `maven-plugin` version (I have a pet project where
   I specified flyway 5.0.0 in `<dependencies>` and use `maven-plugin`
   4.2.0 and it works correctly for you);
2. Specify a path to test-migration via `<location>filesystem:target/test-classes/db/migration</location>` or `<location>filesystem:src/test/resources/db/migration</location>`

I hope it will help you.

P.S. By the way, why do you use migration under test folder for generating classes by jooq? It looks very strange to me. You generate classes from one DB model, but in PROD you will have another DB model (since migrations only under `main` are used). Maybe you should think about it and using only migration under `main` folder? If you have some exceptions while jooq generatinig, try to fix it without `test` migrations.

Comment: Thank you for your investigation! You went deeper in the code than I did and I appreciate that. As I wrote in my previous comment to the question, I went with option 3 and used ```classpath:db/test/migration``` as an additional location and it works. Regarding your question - The classes generated from test folder are just for integration test purposes, it is being used only on maven compilation (therefore added location to ```pom.xml```)  and when running tests locally (added location to ```application-test.yml```), but they are not part of the actual logic of the code.