# Flyway - normalising between "schema_version" / "flyway_schema_history" table names - "Found non-empty schema(s) "PUBLIC" but no schema history table"

Tags: java, h2, flyway

I've been using Flyway in my application, where each use has their own persistent H2 database.

[Flyway v5 changed the metadata table name from `schema_version` to `flyway_schema_history`, and could handle both - but with the caveat Flyway v6 would not do this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49067389)

Due to the databases persisting, and Flyway being upgraded from v4 to v5, some users have a  `schema_version` table, while others have a `flyway_schema_history` table.

Obviously Flyway v6 will not work for the databases with a `schema_version` table.

Initially I was blocked, but then discovered [callbacks](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/callbacks) that allow SQL to be run at arbritrary points. So the obvious solution was a `beforeMigrate.sql` that renamed the `schema_version` table to `flyway_schema_history`.

However when I try this, even though I can see from the debug logs the command is executed, I get the following erorr.
I even get the error when I manually rename the table in the database outside of the callback functionality.

```
org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Found non-empty schema(s) "PUBLIC" but no schema history table. Use baseline() or set baselineOnMigrate to true to initialize the schema history table.
```

I'm getting this whether I tentatively upgrade to Flyway v6 or the latest v8.

Is there something obvious I'm missing? Or is there a smarter way to move these existing databases to a format compatible with the latest flyway versions?

I've created an MVCE using Maven but it's obviously slightly complex as it involves a database etc.

Directory structure:

```
flywaytest
    src
        main
            java
                com
                    me
                        flywaytest
                            FlywayTest.java
            resources
                db
                    migration
                        beforeMigrate.sql
                        V1__Intial.sql
    pom.xml
```

`FlywayTest.java`:

```
package com.me.flywaytest;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.MessageFormat;

import org.flywaydb.core.Flyway;
import org.h2.engine.Constants;

public class FlywayTest {
    private static final String databaseName = "fruits";
    private static final String h2URL = MessageFormat.format("jdbc:h2:~/{0}", databaseName);
    private static final Path databaseLocation = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"))
        .resolve(databaseName + Constants.SUFFIX_MV_FILE);

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        Files.deleteIfExists(databaseLocation);

        createOldDatabase();

        Flyway.configure().dataSource(h2URL, null, null).load().migrate();
    }

    private static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(h2URL, null, null);
    }

    /** Creates an example database as created by Flyway v4.2.0 */
    private static void createOldDatabase() throws Exception {
        // Old Flyway database generated by rolling back Flyway and running an initial
        // migration and dumping it's SQL using the following:
        // Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
        // flyway.setDataSource(h2URL, null, null);
        // flyway.migrate();
        // try (Connection connection = getConnection()) {
        // Script.process(connection,
        // Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home")).resolve(databaseName +
        // ".sql").toString(), "", "");
        // }

        // Which created the following:
        final String fruitsSQL = """
            ;
        CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS "" SALT '' HASH '' ADMIN;
        CREATE CACHED TABLE "PUBLIC"."schema_version"(
            "installed_rank" INT NOT NULL,
            "version" VARCHAR(50),
            "description" VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
            "type" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
            "script" VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
            "checksum" INT,
            "installed_by" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
            "installed_on" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
            "execution_time" INT NOT NULL,
            "success" BOOLEAN NOT NULL
        );
        ALTER TABLE "PUBLIC"."schema_version" ADD CONSTRAINT "PUBLIC"."schema_version_pk" PRIMARY KEY("installed_rank");
        -- 1 +/- SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PUBLIC.schema_version;
        INSERT INTO "PUBLIC"."schema_version" VALUES
        (1, '1', 'Initial', 'SQL', 'V1__Initial.sql', 691111646, '', TIMESTAMP '2021-12-26 00:07:37.878797', 0, TRUE);
        CREATE INDEX "PUBLIC"."schema_version_s_idx" ON "PUBLIC"."schema_version"("success");
        CREATE CACHED TABLE "PUBLIC"."FRUITS"(
            "NAME" CHARACTER VARYING
        );
        -- 0 +/- SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PUBLIC.FRUITS;

        """;

        try (Statement statement = getConnection().createStatement()) {
            statement.execute(fruitsSQL);
        }
    }
}
```

`beforeMigrate.sql`:

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS "schema_version" RENAME CONSTRAINT "schema_version_pk" TO "flyway_schema_history_pk";
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS "schema_version" RENAME TO "flyway_schema_history";
ALTER INDEX IF EXISTS "schema_version_s_idx" RENAME TO "flyway_schema_history_s_idx";
```

`V1__Initial.sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE FRUITS(
    NAME CHARACTER VARYING
);
```

`pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.me</groupId>
    <artifactId>flywaytest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.200</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>8.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally have never used Flyway's callbacks but please, be aware that, according to the [library source code](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/f9bc4c175db54746348191a625386a09e75c4930/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/command/DbMigrate.java#L84), the `beforeMigrate` callback will be run in `DbMigrate` *after* the [schema history table existence is checked](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/f9bc4c175db54746348191a625386a09e75c4930/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/Flyway.java#L135-L173) in the `Flyway` class, so try renaming the history table may not work.

As a possible solution, you could [try providing explicitly the `table` name](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/table) for your databases, keeping the previous one, `schema_version`. For example:

```java
Flyway.configure()
  .table("schema_version")
  .dataSource(h2URL, null, null)
  .load()
  .migrate()
;
```

Probably using the `beforeValidate` callback could work as well, as [that callback seems to be executed before the actual schema history table existence check](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/f9bc4c175db54746348191a625386a09e75c4930/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/Flyway.java#L128-L135). I renamed your script from `beforeMigrate.sql` to `beforeValidate.sql` and it worked properly. Just be sure that validation on migrate is enabled - it should be by default.

Comment: thanks, this makes a lot more sense.
For my simplified example I’ve just shown the old table name, but as per the original questions I have users with databases in both states, so setting the table name to a single value won’t help. However now I know that the callback is happening at the wrong time, and I have a small example, I can see if there is a callback that does what I need, or try running the query manually.

Comment: Sorry @Jakg. I just realized your full comment. I understand. Well, according to the actual migration source code maybe you can try providing a `beforeValidate` callback. This callback seems to be executed before the actual schema history table existence check, so it may help.

Comment: Sorry @Jakg, my previous comment was wrong - I deleted it - I tested `beforeValidate.sql` and it worked properly.

Comment: thanks again, crazy how I was so close to solving this, just using the wrong callback.

Comment: You are welcome @Jakg. In fact, thank you very much, as I said in my answer, I have never used the Flyway callbacks before, and the question helped me dig into them. I found it a very powerful feature indeed.